# wcf service application deploying issue

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I am new to wcf. I have developped a wcf service application(not a library). Can someone tell me how to deploy it other than iis. And how to access the service as a webservice. is this possible and how?

Comment: Are you talking about deploying the service to a server, or hosting it?  You don't have to use IIS - you can use a Windows Service or self-hosting and still access it like a web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) has an example that shows how to deploy a WCF-service as a servicehost application.

This means it runs as a service and does not need to be deployed to an IIS-instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an automatic WCF deploy tool in Visual Studio or copy the code to the server.

The server will be access like through a website like http://localhost:2342342432342/YourWebService.Svc.

You have to get the references from the WS using a tool that generates all the classes for you and you use that service's classes to write your code.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to deploy to to a server that does not use IIS for hosting, you could look at an alternative hosting application like [Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/).